# Text Box Property cannot be changed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating a web page. I've added a `textbox` at design time and changed its `textmode` property to date.

I'm getting the following error when viewing it in a browser: *(if i change the textbox property to "single line" I dont get the error)*

> Parser Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Cannot create an object of type
>
> 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBoxMode' from its string representation
>   'Date' for the 'TextMode' property.

```
Source Error:

Line 20:             <tr>
Line 21:                 <td>
Line 22:                     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox>
Line 23:                 </td>
Line 24:                 <td>&nbsp;</td>
```

Comment: I have just designed the page. just thought of viewing in the browser and I'm getting the error. If i change the textbox property to "single line" I dont get the  error

Comment: @SandraDsouza if you provide your code it will help for better answer to solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please installed .Net Framework 4.5, it will work fine.

Answer (score 5):

It seems you have not installed .Net Framework 4.5. Below .Net Framework 4.5 TextMode has
only three mode i.e. SingleLine, Multiline and password.

Answer (score 3):

This is an alternative answer if you don't want to install the .NET FRK 4.5 :

Instead of using the attribute "TextMode", you can replace it by "type", which is the attribute's name in both cases in the generated "HTML Input"

Answer (score 0):

When you start the new project in Visual Studio IDE, please make sure that .Net Framework 4.5 or higher is selected. That way the project will support these additional features when run.